# How can I send a message to 2 server the bot is in with node discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

I would like it so that when I type a command and a message it will forward that message to a channel in 2 server the bot is connected to with node discord.

Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var message = '[Message]';
bot.channels.get('[ChannelIDServer1]').send(message);
bot.channels.get('[ChannelIDServer2]').send(message);
```

To get the ID of a channel just right click the channel -> copy ID

If you have named your client differently just change `bot` to the name you use.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
```